Confusion in Lemma 21.3 in Forster's Riemann Surfaces

Lemma. Suppose $X$ is a compact Riemann Surfaces of genus $g$. Then there are $g$ distinct points $a_1,\dots,a_g \in X$ with the following property: Every holomorphic 1-form $\omega \in \Omega(X)$ which vanishes at all the points $a_1,\dots,a_g$ is identically $0$.

Proof: For $a\in X$, let $$H_a :=\{\omega\in\Omega(X)\mid \omega(a)=0\}$$
Every $H_a$ is either equal to $\Omega(X)$ or else has codimension one in $\Omega(X)$. Since the intersection of all the $H_a$ is zero and $\Omega(X)$ has dimension $g$, there exist $g$ points $a_1,\dots,a_g$ such that
$$H_{a_1}\cap\dots\cap H_{a_g} =0$$
These points satisfy the conditions of the Lemma. $\blacksquare$
My questions:

Why is every $H_a$ all holomorphic 1-forms or has codimension $1$? Why is it that every 1-form should vanish at $a$ or there is at least a dimension one set of 1-forms which don't vanish at $a$ (the set which does vanish has dimension $g-1$, i.e. codimension one)?
Obviously the only holomorphic 1-form that vanishes everywhere on $X$ is identically $0$, but how does the dimension of $\Omega(X)$ being $g$ imply you only need to consider $g$ points to realize the intersection being $0$? Somehow the basis of $\Omega(X)$ should be enough to find these points?


You get one linear condition on the space of functions if you require them to vanish at a given point. If you’ve learned about the canonical embedding, you can see the points geometrically: (For any non-hyperelliptic curve,) $g$ general points on the canonical curve will span all of $\Bbb P^{g-1}$. Any such $g$ points will do for your question.
